# How do I execute this pseudocode?

Tags: computer-science, education

My son ask me a math question and I can't answer it because I'm too old to remember this. Can anybody help me to solve this and i can help my son to find the answer. thanks in advance

so here the question : 
`
1. given $$a = 10$$
         $$b = 20$$
then
  $$a = a + b$$
  $$b = a + b$$
Find $a,b$.

2. given $$a = 0$$
        $$i = 1$$

$$a = a + 0$$
$$i = a + i$$
loop it five time.
Then $a = ??$`

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: If $a=10$, then $a=10$ ?

Comment: Separate each equalities by a new line. It will be clearer. (Remember $b b$ can be read $b^2$ and I think it's not what you mean)

Comment: I guess in first question, $a=30, b=50.$

Comment: 1. Given $a = 10$, $b = 20$. Then $a' = a+b$. And $b' = a' + b = a+2b$.

  2. Since $a = a+0 = 0$, it is independent of looping (and although not needed, also $i = a+i = i$ always)!

Comment: This seems to be less of a "math question" than a programming question.  In math "=" means equality, but of course it is untrue (when $b\neq 0$) that $a$ is equal to $a+b$.  On the other hand to many programmers "=" will mean "assignment", e.g. replace the original value of $a$ with $a+b$, then replace the original value of $b$ with $a+b$ (using the revised assignment to variable $a$).  So check with your son if this isn't a programming exercise rather than a math exercise.

Comment: i thought it's  a programming exercise. i dont know how there have this questions in my son's junior high school. -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreting the math as a computer program, which is often called [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), we have:

$\quad a \leftarrow 10$

$\quad i \leftarrow 20$

$\quad a \leftarrow a+b \quad \textbf{a=10+20=30}$

$\quad b \leftarrow a+b \quad \textbf{b=30+20=50}$

I've added comments in bold, hoping that this makes things more clear.  So at the end of this code, we have $a=30$ and $b=50$.  For the next code, I've added a loop:

$\quad a \leftarrow 0$

$\quad i \leftarrow 1$

$\quad$ For $j=1$ to $5$ Do

$\quad \quad a \leftarrow a+0 \quad \textbf{a=a}$

$\quad \quad i \leftarrow a+i \quad \textbf{i=1+0=1}$

$\quad$ EndFor

We can observe that $a$ does not change in the loop, since we always add $0$ to $a$, which equals $a$.  So we can basically ignore $a$, which I hope is clear.

Then, having this intuition, we see that $i$ will not change in the loop, since we always add $0$ to it.  So no matter how many times we loop, $i$ will always be equal to $1$.

Comment: Omg. thank you sir. i just recall this in my head. now, i will explain it to my son. hopefully this is what my son looking for.

Comment: @kafi: You're welcome.  If you have more questions like this, you can also try the computer science StackExchange site... https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sir, in the question number 2, how if the given a <- 1, and given b <- 0. is it gonna make a same answer? can you please explain to me?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $i \leftarrow 0$ is given instead of $b \leftarrow 0$.  In this case you'd add $1$ to $i$ five times, so that you'd get $i=5$ at the end of the loop.  You may want to experiment by writing out the loop and seeing what happens.  It helps to have a little bit of intuition.  You may also want to experiment with typing $\LaTeX$, which is the mathematics font system we use.

Comment: how to use latex here? is there any panel to use it like we text editor WYSiWYG?

Comment: Just type in a question, and it will show a preview below.

Comment: ok. thanks sir. i will try it later when i got another question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

So here the question : `
1. given a = 10, b = 20, then a = a + b b = a + b a =? b =?

```
Inicial condiction a=10 and b=20 
a = a + b
b = a + b

FIRST Value
a=10+20=    Now a=30
b=10+20=   and b= 30

Second Value
a=30+30=    Now a=60
b=30+30=   and b= 60

repeat Then  a=b
```

2-)
given a = 0, i = 1
a = a + 0 i = a + i loop it five time. a = ??
`given
a=0
i=1
a=a+0
i=a+i
loop it five time. Then a=??a=??`

```
Inicial condiction a=0 and i=1 
a = a + 0
i = a + i

FIRST Value
a=0+0=    Now a=0
i=0+1=   and i= 1

Second Value
a=0+0=    Now a=0
i=0+1=   and i= 1

repeat and stop when 5 times Then  a=0
```